# Multiple Selection for Database <select> tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to select multiple member to assign to a single Group ! 
For the time being, I can select one member and i can assign him to a single group.
i want to select several members and assign them to a group.

```
    <?php
        include 'connection.php';
        if( isset( $_POST['add_member'] ) )
        {
             $member_id = $_POST['member_id'];
             $group_id = $_POST['group_id'];

             $query="SELECT `id` FROM `member_group`
                        WHERE `member_id` = $member_id AND `group_id` =  $group_id";
            if(!mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection,$query)))
            {
                $query="INSERT INTO `member_group`(member_id,group_id) VALUES( $member_id,$group_id)";
                mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_errno($connection));
                echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>Member Assigned. </div>";
            }
        }
        elseif( isset( $_POST['remove_member'] ) )
        {
             $member_id = $_POST['member_id'];
             $group_id = $_POST['group_id'];

             $query="DELETE FROM `member_group`
                    WHERE `member_id` = $member_id AND `group_id` =  $group_id";
             $rows = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            if(!mysqli_affected_rows($connection))
            {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>Member Already Deleted. </div>";
            }
            else
            {
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>Member Deleted. </div>";
            }
        }

    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label> Add Member to the group: </label>
            <select name="member_id" required="required" name="selectionField"  multiple="yes">
                <option value="">Select a Member</option>
                <?php
                    $member_query = mysqli_query($connection, "select id, member_name , fname , email , mobile from `member`");
                    while($member_data = mysqli_fetch_object($member_query) ){
                        echo "<option value='$member_data->id'>$member_data->member_name</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="add_member" value="Add" class="btn btn-info" />
            <input type="submit" name="remove_member" value="Remove" class="btn btn-info" />
            <select name="group_id" required="required" name="selectionField" multiple="yes">
                <option value="">Select a Group</option>
                <?php
                    $group_query = mysqli_query($connection, "select id, name from `group`");
                    while($group_data = mysqli_fetch_object($group_query) ){
                        echo "<option value='$group_data->id'>$group_data->name</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        <br />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [multiple attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) for select or array of checkboxes.

```
$members_id = is_array($_POST['add_member'])
            ? $_POST['add_member']
            : array($_POST['add_member'];

$check_query = "SELECT `id` FROM `member_group` WHERE `member_id` IN(".implode(',', $members_id).") AND `group_id` =  $group_id";

$already_added = array();
while($member = mysqli_fetch_object($check_query) ){
    $already_added[] = $member->id
}

$members_id = array_diff($members_id, $already_added);

if(count($members_id) > 0) {

    // Add members to DB
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `member_group`(member_id,group_id) VALUES';

    foreach($remove_member as $member_id) {
        $query .= " ($member_id, $group_id)";
    }
    $member_query = mysqli_query($query);
}
```

First query gets already added users, the array of these is then compared to $members_id. Those, who are not in database, are added (second query).

**BTW** if you don't protect your code against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). i.e. using [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<select name="member_id" required="required" name="selectionField" multiple="yes">
```

Do:

```
<select required="required" name="selectionField[]" multiple="yes">
```

This way you are telling PHP that the select is an array with as many positions as elements selected by the user.

To pick up the information in the array:

```
$member_id = $_POST['selectionField'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($member_id);$i++)
{
   $currentMember = $member_id[$i];
// Your code to insert the member in the DB
}
```

Comment: it isn't working , Giving an error "Undefined variable: member_id"

Comment: Also it will make **n** queries for **n** users. It can be inserted via one query.

Comment: Yes. Thanks, I forgot you could add more clauses to value. Your answer is way better than mine.